# Nginx routing for kubernetes services

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-reverse-proxy, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am having same requirements like metioned in this post - https://tech.holidayextras.com/routing-to-internal-kubernetes-services-using-proxies-and-ingress-controllers-e7eb44954d53

But I am not sure of what is that ipaddresses of backends mentioned there. I assumed it is the ips of my master and worker nodes in my cluster

My kubernetes has master node ip as 10.118.6.35 and worker node ip as 10.118.2.215 which are AWS ec2 instances.

So when I configured like below in my nginx.conf(please refer below), I am getting index.html rendered when I do
curl https://10.118.6.35

But when I do https://10.118.6.35/hello-kenzan
I am getting nginx error page default 404 page
But I expect to route it to my kubernetes services running in NodePort 80:30854

I have followed steps as mentioned in that post.
FYI, I am showing the echo-ing.yaml below -

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: echomap
  annotations: {
    'kubernetes.io/ingress.class': nginx
   }
spec:
  rules:
  - host: ip-10-118-6-35.ec2.internal
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /hello-kenzan
        backend:
           service and: hello-kenzan
           service port: 80
```

And below is nginx.conf -

```
http {
       ssl_certificate ...
        ....
        ....
  server {
   listen     443 SSL;
   server_name www.ip-10.118-6-35.ec2.internal.com;
   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
   ssl_certificate ...
   ...
   ...
   include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

   location / {
   }
   error_page 404 /404.html;
      location = /40x.html {
    }
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
      location = /50x.html {
    }
}
upstream backend_nodes {
    server 10.118.6.35:31001;
    server 10.118.2.215:31001;
  }
upstream backend_nodes_ssl {
    server 10.118.6.35:32001;
    server 10.118.2.215:32001;
  }
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name backends.nodes;
     location / {
       proxy_pass https://backend_nodes;
      }
   }
 server {
    listen 443;
    server_name backends.nodes.ssl;
     location / {
       proxy_pass https://backend_nodes_ssl;
      }
   }
}
```

Please suggest what to give for backend node ips

**Update**

Hey finally made it to work when I try with IP address from browser instead of DNS name -

https://10.118.6.35/hello-kenzan  <- this working now
https://myservice.myorg.com/hello-kenzan <- this not working by giving nginx error page temporarily unavailable.

But https://myservice.myorg.com <- works by taking to welcome to nginx index page.

This is my modified nginx.conf -

```
 http {
           ssl_certificate ...
            ....
            ....

server {
       listen     80;
       server_name ip-10.118-6-35.ec2.internal;
       root /usr/share/nginx/html;

       include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

       location / {
       }
       location /hello-kenzan {
           proxy_pass https://backend_nodes;
          }
       error_page 404 /404.html;
          location = /40x.html {
        }
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
          location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
      server {
       listen     443 SSL;
       server_name ip-10.118-6-35.ec2.internal;
       root /usr/share/nginx/html;
       ssl_certificate ...
       ...
       ...
       include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

       location / {
       }
       location /hello-kenzan {
           proxy_pass https://backend_nodes_ssl;
       }
       error_page 404 /404.html;
          location = /40x.html {
        }
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
          location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
    upstream backend_nodes {
        server 10.96.88.237:80
      }
    upstream backend_nodes_ssl {
        server 10.96.88.237:443
      }

  }
```

Any thoughts??

Comment: have you configured nginx ingress controller ?

Comment: Got it to work with DNS name as well

Comment: sorry, can you show how to make proxy_pass https://backend_nodes_ssl; in location /hello-kenzan ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while you are trying with master IP and node Ip is absolutely wrong with the approach of nginx ingress controller. when you add the ingress nginx controller it make load balancer behind (if using aws, digital ocean you check that load balacer in console of it).

```
you have to use the load balancer ip rather then using ip of node and master ip.
```

starting nginx ingress controller

`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/mandatory.yaml`

for more info visit this if any query add comment :

> https://knowihave.blogspot.com/2019/02/how-to-set-up-nginx-ingress-with-cert.html

here at last it's installing cert manager you can remove that part other all thing is easy and simple.

Comment: make  ingress controller and use the ip address of load balancer and add that ip as DNS record you will be done.

Comment: Yes I configured nginx ingress controller. Ok will try the steps you posted in blog link if my setup I did is not working. So in the link I mentioned above I need to provide my load balancer ip in upstream backend nodes in place of master and worker ips??

Comment: you have to expose services as NodePort and using ingress object access it on particular port. service will not have load balancer ingress have load balancer.if you will check tutorial you will get idea

Comment: kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/provider/cloud-generic.yaml
this will make ingress service as load balancer

Comment: But the problem is Loadbalancer is not getting created from nginx ingress, I believe it is due to some restrictions in my organization. I had to run a Jenkins job and manually create the LB. So I have already created ALB with DNS name myservice.mycompany.com and when I access it with https://myservice.mycompany.com it is hitting my Target group ec2 instance by rendering nginx index.html. So now I need to configure in such a way that accessing https://myservice.mycompany.com/hello-kenzan  should route my request to kubernetes SVC hello-kenzan. I believe this can only be done in nginx right?

Comment: yes you are absolutely right you have to route requests to K8s SVC hello-kenzan on particular port.

Comment: Fine. But as mentioned in the link I posted when I did test directly from controller pod by executing `curl localhost` it is showing default backend - 404 but when I did `curl localhost/hello-kenzan` also it is showing default backend. Also please guide me which ip I should mention in that upstream backend nodes. FYI I see this for my `kubectl describe svc hello-kenzan` Type: NodePort IP: 10.99.36.198  Port: <unset> 80/TCP  TargetPort: 80/TCP  NodePort: <unset> 30854/TCP  Endpoints: 192.168.1.146:80  External Traffic Policy: Cluster

Comment: external you have to use

Comment: curl you did from inside pod ?

Comment: if you are trying and testing frequently wait for some time. ingress take 2-3 min to up and running many time with me also happen 404 default backend.

Comment: Yes curl I did from inside pod after I executed `kubectl exec -it nginx-ingress--controller-79fgh66-rr7gh /bin/bash` "external you have to use" - u mean instead of NodePort I need to use external??

Comment: you have to follow till step 2 ..you will have ingress controller with external ip

Comment: External IP is not getting created for me in my application. That's why I followed the approach I posted in which another layer of nginx proxy is used. Please suggest how to proceed with that. Thanks for your time !

Comment: checking your way just give me some time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188090/discussion-between-harsh-manvar-and-gopi).